# How Spring Boot Web Api Can Be Protected/Authorized By Group

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, webapi

I did the following

1. create AAD group "group1"
2. create spring boot web api and has @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_group1')") to protect api by group1
3. configure Security Groups in Token Configuration
4. create Oauth 2.0 access token in Postman using group1 user.
   access token has "groups": ["03652e89-9de8-4ae9-84a5-9798a077d62b"], "03652e89-9de8-4ae9-84a5-9798a077d62b" is oid of group1
5. send the request to api using the access token, receive 403 error, check the log and find Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_api.read] without ROLE_group1

Expectation: that access token's group map to ROLE_group1 in Granted Authorities to support api protection by group.

Problem: How Spring boot web api can be protected by group?

Additional information:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/5-AccessControl/2-call-api-groups provides a sample that angular call .Net web API, and API is protected by group

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory/web-client-access-resource-server/aad-web-application is spring boot web application, it also support the protection by group.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your requirement from my end and got expected results.

***You can refer to my code in [github](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Authorize_Spring_Boot_web-app) to achieve your requirement.***

I have followed the same [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory/web-client-access-resource-server/aad-web-application) which you have provided and configured the client_id, client_secret as per the documentation.

**Results:**
[image]

I'm able to access *group1* and *admin* both the messages as shown below.

[image]

[image]
**ARM client response:**
[image]